# What is the value that indicates a current volatility?

Tags: stock-analysis

In the following chart, the price of the stock dropped when it was around 101.25 to 99.15 on 12/20 and the price is fluctuating between 99.60 and 100.60 for the next three days. Is there any technical indicator (eg. technical term like implied volatility) that will say the price fluctuation is 1 dollar now, to speculate that the trend will continue for the next few weeks?

[image]

Comment: All technical indicators are a look in the rear view mirror, telling you where you have been.  Nothing predicts the future.

Comment: Option prices *predict* the future, but they're mere predictions—they simply show what other traders think is going to happen.